# translate a complex php code of yagendoo

Tags: php

```
<?php if( !empty($YagProduct->prices->salesPrice) ) :   ?>
<?php echo YagendooTmplGlobal::getProductPriceHtml($YagProduct); ?>
```

This code if from Yagendoo Suite and addon of Joomla for Eshops.
This is the 1st time i see something like that and i dont know how to call it and after 5 hours of searching at google i found nothing at all. altough from what i can understand is that $YagProduct is a global class var, with many others variables inside the class. The echo posts 4 html divs . I want to remove the 2 of them so i need some how to translate the variable that getting echoed and get its value so i can edit it.

I tried this:

```
<?php 
$testvar= YagendooTmplGlobal::getProductPriceHtml($YagProduct);
print_r($testvar);
die();
?>
```

with no result. Does anyone have any clue how to translate this ?

Inspect element:

```
<div class="yagVmHomePriceWrap">

    <div class="PricesalesPrice" style="display : block;"></div>
    <div class="yagVmProdPriceAdditional">
        <div class="PricediscountAmount" style="display : block;"></div>
        <div class="PricepriceWithoutTax" style="display : block;"></div>
        <div class="PricetaxAmount" style="display : block;">
            <span class="PricetaxAmount"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="PricediscountedPriceWithoutTax" style="display : block;"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="yagVmFlyProdPriceOld"></div>

</div>
```

php:

```
<?php if( YagParams::get('showPrices') === '1' )    :   ?>
                            <div class="yagVmHomePriceWrap">
                                <?php if( !empty($YagProduct->prices->salesPrice) ) :   ?>


                                        <?php echo YagendooTmplGlobal::getProductPriceHtml($YagProduct); ?>

                                    <?php if( $YagProduct->prices->discountAmount != 0 )    :   ?>
                                        <div class="yagVmFlyProdPriceOld">
                                            <?php echo YagendooTmplGlobal::getProductOldPriceHtml($YagProduct); ?>
                                        </div>
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                    <?php elseif( empty($YagProduct->prices->salesPrice) && YagParams::get('askPrice') === '1' ) : ?>
                                        <a class="yagVmCategoryAskQuestionLink" href="<?php echo $yagVmAskQuestionUrl; ?>" title="<?php echo YagLang::_('YAG_ASK_PRICE'); ?>">
                                            <?php echo YagLang::_('YAG_ASK_PRICE'); ?>
                                        </a>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                            </div>
                        <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the `$testvar` is NULL in which case, print_r will not show you anything so the page will just die() and nothing gets displayed.

Try to echo it with var_dump() like so:

```
<?php 
  $testvar= YagendooTmplGlobal::getProductPriceHtml($YagProduct);
  var_dump($testvar);
  die();
?>
```

And then you can see the exact content of your $testvar and you will be able to debug further.

**USING EXPLODE**

`$exploded = explode(' ', $testvar);`

from here, $exploded will be an array. If you want to ALLWAYS DELETE the 3rd and 5th positions, your array would be something like:

```
$exploded = Array
(
    [0] => 50,00
    [1] => EUR
    [2] => 25,00
    [3] => EUR
    [4] => 82,90
    [5] => EUR
    [6] => 9,35
    [7] => EUR
    [8] => 40,65
    [9] => EUR
)
```

because there is a space between the numbers and the symbol. So you have to be careful when you eliminate from the array.

```
unset($exploded[4]);
unset($exploded[5]);
unset($exploded[8]);
unset($exploded[9]);
```

This will unset position 4,5,8 and 9 so you will delete number and symbol.
After this you just have to implode...

```
$imploded = implode(' ', $exploded);
```

Then, `echo $imploded;` will produce: 50,00 € 25,00 € 9,35 €

Comment: i used that also and im getting this :
string(44) "
"

Comment: so you get a string of 44 characters and a blank space... what type of value does getProductPriceHtml returns?

Comment: ok i used it in the end of the php code and i got this :

string(624) "
50,00 β¬
25,00 β¬
82,90 β¬
9,35 β¬
40,65 β¬
" 

theese are the values of the divs , every div displays one value and then closes. altough how i can edit it now to remove and 3 of 5 values ?

Comment: I dont really know what this β¬ symbol is, but you can preg_match the string with a regex expression... but first you have to find out what that symbol is

Comment: theese are the values:50,00 €
25,00 €
82,90 €
9,35 €
40,65 €
so its the symbol of euro

Comment: another thing you can do is explode the string on space ' ' then get rid of extra values and implode the string again :D

Comment: i tried this :
$var1=YagendooTmplGlobal::getProductPriceHtml($YagProduct);
$vard=str_replace(25,00 β¬,"",$var1); 

but ofc nothing happened. how i do that with explode ? i never used it before

Comment: and i tried also this:
<?php        
$string=YagendooTmplGlobal::getProductPriceHtml($YagProduct);
$s = explode(" ",$string);
unset($s[1]);
unset($s[2]);
unset($s[3]);
$s = implode(" ",$s);
print_r($s);
die();
?>
 but nothing happened again

Comment: check my edit... $s, after implode is string, not array

Comment: ok this acctualy works but the problem is that The Css of page get completly destroyed. seems that we remove the values but not the divs.

Comment: This is because the divs are not in the answer produced by that method call ;) you must trace your code and see exactly where you land upon creating those divs.

Comment: I edited the post . as i can see maybe im wrong is that the divs are actually created in that echo line